# What permissions does a user need in sharepoint to download silverlight xap?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, web-parts

I've created a silverlight webpart using visual studio 2012 in sharepoint 2013. 
The xap file has been deployed to /SiteAssets/MySilverlightProject/SilverlightWebPart1/silverlightControl.xap
Now, it works fine for site collection administrator but for normal users I receive following errror:

> Could not download silverlight application.

So, I guess it should be a permission problem. If I'm right then I would need to know what permissions does a particular user need to be able to view a silverlight webpart?

Comment: I dont think it should be a permissions issue. Security for downloading a XAP would be like security for viewing an HTML page. It goes into your internet cache. Do they have silverlight (viewer) already installed (and for the correct version of SL)?

Comment: Yes on same machine with admin users works but normal user credentials doesn't work. However, I deployed the solution to Layout folder now it's downloadable for all users. Seemingly, siteAssets folder is accessible for a certain permission level.